# AWS ECS add Task from Step Function fails pulling container

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-step-functions, amazon-ecr

I tried to add / run Task in my ECS Cluster as part of workflow in Step Function State Machine that being defined as:

```
"AddTaskToRun": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
    "Cluster": "fargate-taks-poc-data-dev-cluster",
    "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-1:111111111111:task-definition/fargate-taks-poc-dev-task-definition:1",
    "NetworkConfiguration": {
      "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
        "SecurityGroups": [
          "sg-111111"
        ],
        "Subnets": [
          "subnet-111111"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Next": "PublishAddTaskSuccess"
},
```

I am using default security group with allow all traffic and one of default subnets. Also in this subnet there are 3 VPC Endpoints created:

- .ecr.dkr
- .ecr.api
- .logs

However when I execute state machine it adding task to Cluster but goes only to PENDING state and error out with message:

```
 CannotPullContainerError: ref pull has been retried 5 time(s): failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: failed to do request: Get \"https://prod-us-west-1-starport-layer-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/5ffb42-557844393866-ccc37f9d-f80f-a1a8-1327-d0a4ff9f9e52.........
```

Image for Task in defined in ECR Repository.

What I missing?

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130737/ecs-fargate-task-fails-cannotpullcontainererror-inspect-image-has-been-retried

Answer (score 0):

I believe your VPC needs a fourth endpoint: a S3 [Gateway Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/gateway-endpoints.html).  It's required because ECR [stores](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/setting-up-aws-privatelink-for-amazon-ecs-and-amazon-ecr/) the Docker image layers in S3.

This diagnosis seems to fit with the bucket-related `failed to copy` error message.

Comment: I did not mentioned it but I also have Endpoint to S3 as Gateway - also added as Interface and still same results

Answer (score 0):

If you have added a S3 Gateway Endpoint and the issue still persists, take a look at this troubleshooting guide: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/connect-s3-vpc-endpoint

The gist is:

- Make sure that the route to the gateway endpoint was added to the route table.
- Make sure that there is no security group blocking the access.
- Make sure that your network ACL rules allow outbound traffic and (!) inbound traffic on ephemeral ports.